# Using python-solidity-parser, is there a way to convert the ast file back into solidity?

Tags: python, parsing, solidity

I want to manipulate a solidity file, such as changing some variable names or changing, and then convert back into solidity file. Is there a way to do this using the python-solidity-parser project?

I did find a javacript one,  haven't tested yet though.  https://github.com/ConsenSys/solc-typed-ast